# woocommerce cart custom thumbnail image image in cart

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show custom thumbnail images in cart. I made product with a custom attribute, say `imageurl`.

I used the hook below to make it work:

```
function custom_new_product_image($cart_object) {
    $a = '<img src="imageurlhere" />';
    return $a;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_new_product_image' );
```

My code works well if I put a static url in place of `"imageurlhere"` but I want to pass a custom product attribute image url.

I am able to get the image url with

```
$cart_object->cart_contents['wccpf_imageurl']
```

How do I use a custom product attribute image url in place of a static one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function custom_new_product_image( $_product_img, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $a      =   '<img src="'.$cart_item['wccpf_width'].'" />';
    return $a;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_new_product_image', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Okay you have added the product attribute named `imageurl` which has the URL of the image that you expect, right??

Comment: yeah i want to show that as product thubmnail image in cart

Comment: what is 10,3 i just pasted it still seems not working i get blank src

Comment: when i use <img src="'.$cart_item["product_id"]].'" /> it show product id

Comment: 10 is priority of the filter and the 3 is number of arguments to be passed!

Comment: can you help me with task will pay for same it is small task if u interested

Answer (score 0):

To change the thumbnail image size of WooCommerce cart page you need next steps:

**Step-1**: in function.php create the size you need.

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 100, 100 ); // 100 wide and 100 high
}
```

**Step-2**: in cart.php which should be located in your_tneme\woocommerce\cart find

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

and in get_image() write the name of your size. In our case, it will be like this: get_image(‘custom-thumb’)

**Step-3**: If you check the image source, you can see that the image size is changed. But still, you may need to customize the CSS to display your expected style.

Checked work on WooCommerce latest version 3.7.1